# Convert image URI into javascript file object

Tags: javascript, uri

So I have this webcam feature that returns base64 URI to me and I can't save it to AWS since it needs an image object. Is there any way to convert URI into javascript object?(file object the same as returned by file browser input tag to be exact)

I want to convert this

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

into this

```
File {
   lastModified : 1481782908707
   lastModifiedDate : Thu Dec 15 2016 14:21:48 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
   name : "sampleicon2.jpg"
   size :64847
   type : "image/jpeg"
   webkitRelativePath : ""
   __proto__ : File
}
```

Is it possible? How? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

fastest way

```
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}
```

Usage example:

```
var file = dataURLtoFile('data:image/png;base64,....', 'filename.png');
console.log(file);
```

Comment: Wow, you just saved me from lots of trouble. It works perfectly thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanx alot, your answer is saviour for me. @HarelLevy

Comment: I am using this code for converting image file but i have got error "cannot read property  1 of null"

Comment: mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]),