# How to convert image source into a JavaScript File object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fileapi

I have an image URL `"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0234/8017/2591/products/young-man-in-bright-fashion_925x_f7029e2b-80f0-4a40-a87b-834b9a283c39.jpg"`, and want to convert it into javaScript File Type object.

```
: File
   lastModified: 1591250106736
   lastModifiedDate: Thu Jun 04 2020 11:25:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard 
   Time) {}
   name: "7.jpeg"
   size: 369742
   type: "image/jpeg"
   webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get it. You have a path to an image. Ok. What do you want to do with that path? Or with the image. "Convert it to File Type" makes no sense for me.

Comment: @Torf I think the OP wants to get the file as a browser `File` object

Comment: @Torf, i want to convert image source into browser `File` object

Comment: Maybe that has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358456/convert-image-uri-into-javascript-file-object

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Convert your image src `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0234/8017/2591/products/young-man-in-bright-fashion_925x_f7029e2b-80f0-4a40-a87b-834b9a283c39.jpg` into `Base64 ULR` format and than convert `Base64 URL` into javaScript `File` Object.

```
***Here is the code for converting "image source" (url) to "Base64".***

let url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0234/8017/2591/products/young-man-in-bright-fashion_925x_f7029e2b-80f0-4a40-a87b-834b9a283c39.jpg'
const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
      reader.onerror = reject
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
     }))


***Here is code for converting "Base64" to javascript "File Object".***

  function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
     var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
     bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
     while(n--){
     u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
     }
   return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
  }


*** Calling both function ***

  toDataURL(url)
  .then(dataUrl => {
     console.log('Here is Base64 Url', dataUrl)
     var fileData = dataURLtoFile(dataUrl, "imageName.jpg");
     console.log("Here is JavaScript File Object",fileData)
     fileArr.push(fileData)
   })
```

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming you want to run this in a browser environment.
You can use the native `fetch()` method, read the response as `Blob` and convert it to a `File` object.

`contentType` should be based on the type of the actual image downloaded.

You can read more about several approaches and browser support to convert a `Blob` to `File` here:

[Convert blob to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553617/convert-blob-to-file)

[How to convert Blob to File in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript)

```js
const url = 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0234/8017/2591/products/young-man-in-bright-fashion_925x_f7029e2b-80f0-4a40-a87b-834b9a283c39.jpg?v=1572867553'
const fileName = 'myFile.jpg'

fetch(url)
  .then(async response => {
    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
    const blob = await response.blob()
    const file = new File([blob], fileName, { contentType })
    // access file here
  })
```

Comment: any pointers on how to also attach a temporary path for the File object?

Comment: @thammada.ts When I used this, I got text/html for the file type, and the link was an image.. any idea how to solve this? thanks

Comment: @user10033434 the content type is sent by the target server. It's possible that the link you are fetching returns an incorrect type in the header. If you are sure about the content type you can used a fixed value like for example `contentType: 'image/jpeg'` or `contentType: 'image/png'`

Answer (score 9):

For more elegant solution use this

```
const getUrlExtension = (url) => {
    return url
      .split(/[#?]/)[0]
      .split(".")
      .pop()
      .trim();
  }

const onImageEdit = async (imgUrl) => {
    var imgExt = getUrlExtension(imgUrl);

    const response = await fetch(imgUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const file = new File([blob], "profileImage." + imgExt, {
      type: blob.type,
    });
}
```

Comment: I received "Failed to fetch" when I gave it an URL of an image on AWS S3.
Why is that? the image can be seen on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Alphapico works like a charm, just have to return the file:

```
const onImageEdit = async (imgUrl) => {
    var imgExt = getUrlExtension(imgUrl);

    const response = await fetch(imgUrl);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const file = new File([blob], "profileImage." + imgExt, {
      type: blob.type,
    });
    
    return file;

}
```

might be case to case scenario